# Как запустить python телеграмм бота на сервере VDS?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, vds

Есть бот на Python. Командой `python3 main.py` отлично запускается и работает. Но как мне его запустить на сервер? Доступ к VDS осуществляется через консоль. После закрытия консоли процесс Python останавливается. Пробовл запускать, потому `ctrl+z; $ bg %1; $ disown %1`, всё равно падает. Что делать?

Comment: Можно прописать как сервис `systemd`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, ну когда уже будешь писать ответы в ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну когда уже кто-нибудь напишет канонический вопрос вида «Как запустить процесс в фоне/в автозагрузке на Linux-сервере», чтобы все подобные вопросы можно было смело закрывать как дубликат)

Comment: @andreymal, а давай сам)

Answer (score 1):

самое простое - запускать с помощью screen - https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/screen

так же есть менеджеры процессов типа pm2 - https://blog.pm2.io/2018-09-19/Manage-Python-Processes/

Answer (score 1):

Напишите службу для запуска бота:

```
cat > /etc/systemd/system/<название сервиса>.service << EOF
```

Прописываем туда это, подставивисвои данные

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=<Путь к боту>
User=user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

затем в консоли

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable foobar
systemctl start foobar
systemctl status foobar
```